# MonetDB - column imprints vs column cracking

Tags: indexing, monetdb, columnstore

I stumbled upon these two concepts in various white papers related to MonetDB. Seems like both aim and accomplishing similar goal - speeding up selections for range queries. Are these two concepts implemented in MonetDB in tandem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database cracking approach is mostly studied in isolation.
Imprints is an integral part of the software distribution.
regards, Martin